# Retrieve information from URL to share it on my website

Tags: web-services, information-retrieval

I am about to develop a new feature on my website that allow the user to give me a URL then I would use this URL to get the site title, description and image(s) so that I store these information on my website. I need to know if there is any script that can do that or if there is a web service that would take the url and give me the information I need or shall I start developing this from scratch.

Also, I would like to know if there is any kind of standards used in the information sharing mechanism as I want to allow the user to share a video or photo from the web.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single script that can extract information from all sites, because the source HTML for most websites is different. You will need to write code specifically for the sites you are scraping.

As for syndicating the content, you can use RSS (Really Simple Syndication), which is an XML format commonly used for sharing content.